# Pandas - unstack with duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, pivot

I have tried to unstack a dataframe with duplicates jumping through different hoops. So far without result. I would be grateful for any help:

I have a dataframe that have a 'long' format:

```
| id | variable  | value |
|----|-----------|-------|
| 1  | outcome_1 | NaN   |
| 2  | outcome_1 | 18:33 |
| 2  | outcome_1 | 20:39 |
| 2  | outcome_3 | 01:40 |
| 3  | outcome_2 | 03:59 |
| 3  | outcome_4 | 07:46 |
| 3  | outcome_3 | 10:53 |
```

And would like to convert it to a 'wide' format, but without aggregation and preserving all values, so the result would look like this:

```
| id_nmbr | outcome_1_0 | outcome_1_1 | outcome_2_0 | outcome_3_0 | outcome_4_0 |
|---------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
| 1       | NaN         | NaN         | NaN         | NaN         | NaN         |
| 2       | 18:33       | 20:39       | NaN         | 01:40       | NaN         |
| 3       | NaN         | NaN         | 03:59       | 07:46       | 10:53       |
```

So basically, preserve each value, and create a new column for each duplicate.

I have tried pivot or unstack, as well as pivot_table, but I think I need to string some functions together to achieve it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, then reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with sorting `MultiIndex` and flatten in `map`:

```
g = df.groupby(['id','variable']).cumcount()

df = df.set_index(['id','variable', g])['value'].unstack([1,2]).sort_index(axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   id outcome_1_0 outcome_1_1 outcome_2_0 outcome_3_0 outcome_4_0
0   1         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
1   2       18:33       20:39         NaN       01:40         NaN
2   3         NaN         NaN       03:59       10:53       07:46
```

Answer (score 1):

[pivot_wider](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_wider.html) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) can help to abstract the reshaping process:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

 # the cumcount helps to get a unique index
(df.assign(counter = df.groupby(group).cumcount())
   .pivot_wider(index='id', 
                names_from=['variable', 'counter'], 
                values_from='value')
) 
   id outcome_1_0 outcome_1_1 outcome_3_0 outcome_2_0 outcome_4_0
0   1         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
1   2       18:33       20:39       01:40         NaN         NaN
2   3         NaN         NaN       10:53       03:59       07:46
```